# AdvancedFilter creates a named range

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a sheet (lets call it `NR`) which holds named ranges I use as data validation lists in other sheets (about 10 list). One of the list is updated from another sheet (lets call this `Sheet1`). I use the below code to get the unique values from `Sheet1` column **A** into `NR` sheet:

```
iLRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("A3:A" & iLRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=NR.Range("D2"), Unique:=True
```

Problem is, everytime I run the above code, it seems to create a Named range called **`Extract`**. This is causing me a bit of an issue. Just wanted to find out if this is a known behaviour or is this a bug of some sort? I cannot seem to delete this range using VBA although I can delete it manually using `Name Manger` tool

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems to be known, eg. http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19763-Advanced-Filter-Creating-Named-Range

Comment: Hmm, bizarre behaviour. Thanks for the reference @SJR

Answer (score 0):

As per SJR's comment, closing this query as this seems to be a known behaviour